# Group pandas df based of contigous 0's but only change a few based on condition

Tags: python, pandas

So my data is like below:

| startTimestamp | status |
| --- | --- |
| 1Jan 00:00 | 0 |
| 1Jan 01:00 | 1 |
| 1Jan 02:00 | 0 |
| 1Jan 03:00 | 1 |
| 1Jan 04:00 | 1 |
| 1Mar 21:00 | 1 |
| 1Mar 22:00 | 0 |
| 1Mar 23:00 | 0 |
| 2Mar 00:00 | 1 |
| 2Mar 01:00 | 0 |
| 2Mar 02:00 | 0 |
| 2Mar 03:00 | 1 |
| 2Mar 04:00 | 1 |
| 2Mar 05:00 | 1 |
| 2Mar 06:00 | 0 |
| 2Mar 07:00 | 0 |
| 2Mar 08:00 | 1 |
| 1Apr 00:00 | 0 |

total 2161 rows. Rows are omitted due to space. 90days * 24 hour bins per day = 2161 rows

Essentially hourly binned data for 90 days. So 2161 rows. 0 means 'down', 1 means 'working fine'. I am faced with below challenges:

from 23:00 to 6:00am on any given day if the system was down (0) strictly within 23 - 6 we change this to up (1), as in these hours are off work hours. So 2Mar 01:00  & 2Mar 02:00 will be changed to up (1) as these fall within 23- 6am interval.
However if system went down before 23 and continued into the window i.e. 23 onwards it shall not be made to up, as this is not related to window downtime (23-6am). So  1Mar 22:00 & 1Mar 23:00 will not be made up. Similarly, 2Mar 06:00  & 2Mar 07:00 will not be made up.

This can be essentially thought of as finding boundary cases where downtime started before 23 or ended well after 6am. But this isn't as easy as i thought. My data is in pandas df with 2161 rows. I need to find an efficient way to change only thoose downtimes (0) to up (1) where downtime was strictly within 23 - 6am. i.e. system downtime did not start at 22 or downtime did not last after 6am

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use loc for this i've just used index but you can maybe incoporate some datetime and string/regex logic for finding the date and use that for your upper and lower bounds.

```
# 1st.
ss = {'x':[1,2,3,4,5], 'y':[0,1,1,1,0]}
ss = pd.DataFrame(ss)
ss.head()
# with filter
ss.loc[(ss.index >= 1) & (ss.index <= 3), 'y'] = 0
ss.head()
```

head raw:

[image]

[image: filter]

maybe sudo code ex:

```
def string_to_date(str):
#return datetime object or utc milliseconds

#then
ss.loc[(string_to_date(dataframe['col']) >= datetime) & (string_to_date(dataframe['col']) <= datetime), 'y'] = 0
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but subsetting timestamp between 23 - 6am is not a problem. It is making sure we do not modify cases where value was down(0) before 23 and down after 6am. Like 2 mar 6am , 2march 7am. 23pm and 6am act as boundary so if system went down strictly within 23-6 only then change it to up

Comment: Couldn't you just pass an extra set of () to the loc.  something like find row before lower bound and find it's status and if that's true then change all between lower and upper? or just wrap the entire loc in an if statement where you find the row before and based on the status do loc

Comment: I could but there are many scenarios. If 10pm,11pm down dont change both. If 1am, 2am down but 3am up change. If 4am,5am,6am down but 7am up then change all 3 to 1. But lets say 7am was down too then dont change any of 4am,5am,6am,7am. I can think of it like finding contigous 0's and 1's logic but not sure